# OpenCV and reading data from OutputArrays or (Mat)

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have a couple of problems with OpenCV's own functions for PnP and Rodrigues formula. I think it is related to `cv::solvePnPRansac()`

```
 cv::Mat w = cv::Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_32FC1);
 cv::Mat t = cv::Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_32FC1);
 std::vector<float> distortion = {0,0,0,0};

 std::vector<cv::Point3f> tmp1 = eig_vec_to_cv3(pts);
 std::vector<cv::Point2f> tmp2 =  eig_vec_to_cv2(pixels);

 cv::solvePnPRansac(tmp1, tmp2, eig_mat_2_cv(K),distortion, w, t,false, 100, 2.0f);

 cv::Mat R_ = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_32FC1);
 cv::Rodrigues(w,R_);

 std::cout<<"R_"<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<R_<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<R_.at<float>(0,0)<<std::endl;
```

For `std::cout<<R_<<std::endl` it looks ok, but `R_.at<float>(0,0)` gives a trash number, like the memory is not allocated. The same holds for `w` and `t`.

However, if I make like this:

```
cv::Mat w_ = cv::Mat(3,1,cv_32FC1);
w.at<float>(0,0) = 0.2;
w.at<float>(0,1) = 0.4;
w.at<float>(0,2) = 0.3;

cv::Rodrigues(w_,R_);

std::cout<<"R_"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<R_<<std::endl;
std::cout<<R_.at<float>(0,0)<<std::endl;
```

It works just fine.

This is a minimal (non)-working example:

```
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat w = cv::Mat(3,1,CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat t = cv::Mat(3,1, CV_32FC1);

    std::vector<cv::Point3f> tmp1;
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> tmp2;

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
    {
        cv::Point3f p1(0.2f+k, 0.3f-k, 7.5f-k);
        cv::Point2f p2(3.2f*k, 4.5f/k);
        tmp1.push_back(p1);
        tmp2.push_back(p2);
    }

    cv::Mat K = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    K.at<float>(0,0) = 525.0;
    K.at<float>(0,2) = 234.5;
    K.at<float>(1,1) = 525;
    K.at<float>(1,2) = 312.5;
    K.at<float>(2,2) = 1.0f;

    std::vector<float> distortion = {0,0,0,0};

    cv::solvePnPRansac(tmp1, tmp2, K,distortion, w, t,false, 100, 2.0f);

    std::cout<<w<<std::endl;
    cv::Mat R = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    cv::Rodrigues(w,R);
    std::cout<<R<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<R.at<float>(0,0)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/opencv4/ -o test -L /usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the function `cv::Rodrigues` creates the output matrix of type `CV_64FC1`. So the values have to be read as follows:

```
std::cout<<R.at<double>(0,0)<<std::endl;
```

Even if we pre-allocate the output matrix to be of any other type ( say `CV_32FC1` ), it will be reallocated by `cv::Rodrigues` to type `CV_64FC1`.

In my opinion, the OpenCV documentation lacks clarity about the input and output types of many functions. In cases like these, one must be sure about the output types by printing the return value of `Mat::type()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think the OpenCV documentation is questionable in many ways. In particular for python.

Comment: @El_Loco.. Yes indeed. Even the primary language (C++) has some ambiguous documentation. I guess it is time to start contributing to the code base and improve its documentation. :)

Comment: @El_Loco.. Also, you may consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @sgarizvi Now is a great time to contribute---the OpenCV hackathon starts this weekend! https://opencv.org/opencv-hackathon-is-coming/